# is Service an abstract class?

Tags: android

This question was asked in an interview, let me know if anyone does know, while I crawl the web for the answer and understanding..

**Edit**

found it...

Comment: Nice... ask first, search later...

Comment: @WarrenFaith, asking is part of the searching :-)

Comment: my bad, its one of those weak moment of laziness,lol

Comment: The google magic search was: `android service`, for what it's worth. :)

Comment: found the what i was looking for , in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/app/Service.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html